# What is the difference between Jacobian of maps between manifolds and matrix representation of its differential?

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds

In *An Introduction to Manifolds* by Loring Tu p.67 and 91, the author first defined the "Jacobian matrix" (see the picture) of maps between manifolds relative to corresponding charts. And then in p.91, he discuss local expression of differential (which is a linear transformation between tangent spaces) and discuss its matrix representation. However, I want to ask is these two things literally the same?
[image]

Comment: It seems that you have doubts. Can you explain where do you see a problem?

Comment: I wonder is Jacobian of a map $f:N\to M$ between manifolds and matrix representation of its differential turn out to be the same thing? If so, and if our purpose is to approximate the map by a linear transformation, we don't need to discuss differential between tangent spaces right? Only Jacobian of $f$ wrt two chosen charts is enough .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a map $ f : U \to V$ between open subsets $U \subset \mathbb R^m, V \subset \mathbb R^n$, then the derivative at $p \in U$ is the best linear approximation of $f$ in $p$. This is the (unique) linear map $df(p) : \mathbb R^m \to \mathbb R^n$ such that $$\lim_{h  \to 0} \dfrac{\lVert f(p+h) - (f(p) + df(p)(h)) \rVert}{\lVert h \rVert} = 0. $$
Note that for the above quotient to be well-defined it is *essential* that $U \subset \mathbb R^m$ (so that $p + h$ is defined) and $V \subset \mathbb R^n$ (so that $f(p+h) - (f(p) + df(p)(h))$ is defined).

If we have a map $F : M \to N$ between general manifolds, we obviously cannot define the derivative of $F$ at $p \in M$ as above: Neither there exists a sum $p + h \in M$ for $p \in M$ and (sufficiently small) $h \in \mathbb R^m$ nor the expression $f(p+h) - (f(p) + df(p)(h))$  makes any sense.

What we can do is to choose coordinate systems $(U,\varphi)$ at $p \in M$ and $(V,\psi)$ at $F(p) \in N$ such that $F(U) \subset V$. Then $F_{\varphi,\psi} = \psi \circ F  \circ \varphi^{-1}$ is a map between open subsets of Euclidean spaces which has a derivative $d_{\varphi,\psi}F(p) = dF_{\varphi,\psi}(\varphi^{-1}(p)) : \mathbb R^m \to \mathbb R^n$. This depends on the *coice* of the coordinate systems, i.e. this approach does not produce a derivative of $F$ in an absolute sense. However, the canonical matrix representation of $d_{\varphi,\psi}F(p)$ is the Jacobian matrix of $F_{\varphi,\psi}$.

The tangential space $T_p M$ of a manifold $M$ at $p \in M$ is defined without reference to any coordinate system at $p$. Howewer, any choice of a coordinate system $(U,\varphi)$ at $p$ yields a specific linear isomorphism $\iota_\varphi : \mathbb R^m \to T_pM$. The derivative $F_{*,p} : T_pM \to T_{F(p)]}N$ can be defined without reference to coordinate systems - it has a *coordinate-free* meaning. This is an essential benefit of working with tangential spaces.

Proposition 8.11 describes the relation between betwen the coordinate-free concept of derivative $F_{*,p}$ and the "classical" derivatives $d_{\varphi,\psi}F(p)$ depending on the choice of coordinates. In fact, we have a commutative diagram

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
\mathbb R^m @>{d_{\varphi,\psi}F(p)}>> \mathbb R^n \\
@V{\iota_\varphi }VV @V{\iota_\psi }VV \\
T_pM @>{F_{*,p}}>> T_{F(p)}N
\end{CD}

in which the vertical arrows are isomorphisms depending on $\varphi,\psi$.

Comment: I come back to continue studying manifold, and read the answer again. Really helps! Thanks.

Comment: A little question. I know that $F_{*,p} : T_pM \to T_{F(p)]}N$ is coordinate-free. But the function $F:M\to N$ at the begin of the whole story is also coordinate-free. So why don't we just study $F$? And even though $F_{*,p} : T_pM \to T_{F(p)]}N$ is coordinate-free, if we wish to really analyze such abstract function, we need to use $\iota_{\varphi}$ and $\iota_{\psi}$ to transform them to Euclidean space right (so that it becomes a linear transformation on vector spaces $\Bbb R^m$ and $\Bbb R^n$)? So it roughly seems that the benefit of being coordinate free will gone. Where am I wrong?

Comment: @Eric This is not a little question, but a very serious one, albeit it has a "philosophical" touch. You should ask a new question.